# Почему результат "0 Привет Пока " ? Именно 0 меня интересует

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>//библиотека для команды  strcat_s.
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    char chSud[50] = " Привет ";
    char chRyb[50] = " Пока ";
    cout << strcat_s(chSud, chRyb);//strcat_s-команда для объединения строк.[![ Visual Studio 2015][1]][1]
    cout << chRyb;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Показанная вами программа не может произвести тот вывод на консоль, на который вы ссылаетесь в вопросе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если бы вы прочитали документацию на strcat_s вы бы видели, что возвращает эта функция код ошибки (0 если успешно). И именно возвращаемое значение вы передаете в cout. Вот и ноль на экране.

Comment: А слово "привет" при этом копируется во второй параметр функции и печатается уже при `cout << chRyb`

Comment: Ошибку я понял(после 5 минут в интернете) ,а вот про 0 вы мне разъяснили , спасибо.

Comment: @Mike Как слово "Привет " может копироваться во второй аргумент?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Пересмотрел описание strcat_s. dest там действительно первым параметром, правда в этом случае я не понимаю откуда на выводе слово "привет".

Comment: @Mike меня тоже смущает наличие там "привет", но вполне вероятно что выполняется не тот код, что тут.